# What is the best strategy to acknowledge a specific file format in a shared Model?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, file-upload

I have an Attachment model that generically handles all forms of attachments ( .zip, .png, .pdf, etc. ).

Using the same model logic ( handling files, associating them to similar objects, and uploading/retrieving from S3 ), I would like to somehow differentiate between a .zip file that is attached as a regular zip attachment ( this is default behavior and currently working ), and I also would like to be able to upload a zip file that the server needs to especially unzip, extract the files, and perform a process.

So the two file types are :

1. A default zip file that just gets saved and stored on S3. This is working.
2. A zip file that requires the server to perform special treatment to it.

I thought that in order to accomplish this, I could pass a parameter within the file name of the attachment in the HTML... My best guess is something like this :

```
<input name="attachment?special_treatment=true" type="file" size="19" style="opacity: 0;">
```

I'm pretty sure this would not work. But is there a way to pass a parameter with the file itself, or within its Header so that my App can then register that this Attachment requires special treatment?

Terribly sorry if this makes no sense!